# psycopg2 - multiple insert, but insert one common timestamp

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp, psql

I am trying to insert to multiple tables, but have them share only one timestamp. I am implementing something like this:

```
for table in table_names:
    current_utc_time = str(datetime.utcnow())
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.{0} VALUES({1}, {2})".format(table, current_utc_time, foo))
```

But this set of code throws me the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/EricKim/Documents/sage/fake_data_push.py", line 58, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.{0} VALUES({1}, {2})".format(table, current_utc_time, df.iloc[row_num, col_num]))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "16"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.rt_torqx VALUES(2018-08-30 16:26:35.20088...
```

There must be some formatting error, but I do now know what's wrong, because to my understanding `2018-08-30 16:26:35.20088` is the right format of pgsql timestamp string format. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against Python string `format()` for your parameters. Instead, use `psycopg2` parameter passing via `%s`, which will do type conversion for you. Something like:

```
right_now = datetime.utcnow()
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO public.{table} VALUES(%s, %s)', (right_now, df.iloc[row_num, col_num],))
```

(Not tested, but the gist is 1) use the f-string (or `.format()`) only for the table name, since that's not a parameter, and 2) use the `%s` placeholders for actual parameters; you may need to cast the df value via `str()`... depends on the data type in question)

See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries